# Different behavior for pipenv (not) using pyenv when using gitlab-runner with singularity

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci-runner, pipenv, pyenv, singularity-container

## Background

Trying to find an easy, automated way to mirror local python apps from different environments (with different dependencies) into running containers, I use a bunch of different tools:

Local machine: Windows, VSCode, GitLab Workflow extension, pipenv, python, flask,...

Server LinuxVM: Ubuntu with a gitlab-runner user, singularity for containerization

GitLab: for Code version control and GitLab-Runner for "deploying" on Server LinuxVM

Repository files: some-python-file.py, Pipfile, .gitlab-ci.yml, singularity-build-plan.def

Using the .gitlab-ci.yml file, the GitLab-Runner runs on the Server LinuxVM, copies the repository there, copies Pipfile and singularity-build-plan.def to a new folder and starts building the newcontainer.sif file there using singularity and the singularity-build-plan.def file.

```
sudo singularity build --force newcontainer.sif singularity-build-plan.def
```

The singularity-build-plan.def uses the ubuntu:latest image, updates it, installs some necessary packages, installs pyenv and installs pipenv and(!) installs a new pipenv environment based on the python version defined in the Pipfile.

## Problem

==> But instead using pyenv to grab and install the python version defined in the Pipfile, it uses the system python:

```
Warning: Python 3.7 was not found on your system...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /data/apps/Pipfile
Using default python from /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.12) to create virtualenv...
[...]
✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /data/apps/.venv
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using 3.10.12 (/data/apps/.venv/bin/python).
[...]
```

## Curiosity Nr. 1

When I take the same files but connect from my Windows PC to the Server LinuxVM via Putty (and change user via sudo su gitlab-runner) and execute the same command

```
sudo singularity build --force newcontainer.sif singularity-build-plan.def,
```

it works fine:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /data/apps/Pipfile
Using /data/apps/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/bin/python3.7m (3.7.17) to create virtualenv...
[...]
✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /data/apps/.venv
[...]
```

## Curiosity Nr. 2

If here instead of using

```
sudo singularity build --force newcontainer.sif singularity-build-plan.def
```

I use

```
sudo singularity build --force newcontainer.sif singularity-build-plan.def >> output.txt
```

it is not working again:

```
Warning: Python 3.7 was not found on your system...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /data/apps/Pipfile
Using default python from /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.12) to create virtualenv...
[...]
✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /data/apps/.venv
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using 3.10.12 (/data/apps/.venv/bin/python).
[..]
```

And back to

```
sudo singularity build --force newcontainer.sif singularity-build-plan.def
```

it works fine.

Any ideas where this could come from? Or what I could do to find the cause? I really want to get it to work with the GitLab-Runner so I can just threw a new python code (from somone else) into a repository and it will deploy automatically in a container with the correct python version and virtual environment in it.
As it is working while on a Putty connection and not using "[...] >> output.txt" I assume that $PATH, Variables, etc. are correct. But the environment somehow changes. But where...?

Any idea would be appreciated.